# Linq + SQLite + Take() == Problem

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, skip, take

I'm using System.Data.SQLite to access a SQLite database via c#/linq. I had no problems until I tried to use the Take()/Skip() functionality which caused an exception. The error message in case of Take() is "SQLite error near ".": syntax error".
Any ideas what I could do to get around this?

Comment: Are you using the most recent version of System.Data.SQLite?

Comment: At the moment: No. I did not notice until yesterday and have to wait for my admin to install the most recent version. I'll let you know how it went.

Comment: With version 1.0.73.0 I still have the problem.

Comment: I believe the latest version is 1.0.66.0. You can try examining the generated SQL (cast the query to `ObjectQuery` and call `ToTraceString`), or just ask in the [SQLite forum](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/29.aspx) - the maintainers don't monitor SO regularly.

Comment: I updated to this [fork](http://system.data.sqlite.org), which seems to have more recent versions.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps you need DBLinq  http://code.google.com/p/dblinq2007/

Comment: Where does DBLinq stand in all this? It seems to use System.Data.SQLite, but maybe it makes its own LINQ to SQL conversion?

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue using VS2008 SP1, `System.Data.Sqlite.Linq v2.0.38.0` and `System.Data.Sqlite v1.0.66.0`.
Solved a similar error (with LINQ's `Skip`) uncommenting `DbProviderFactories` section in app.config, don't ask me why it works.
That section shows this way:

```
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite"/>
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

(I'm working with and old VS2008 project after an OS reinstall and I had to reinstall all dependencies, I think I've not installed the same exact Sqlite versions I had. It always worked with that app.config's section commented)

Comment: Worked for me too, .net framework 4.8, C# 8 activated. Newest System.Data.SQLite.Linq NuGet package installed. Anyway, after removing the NeGet package it worked without the app.config. I assume this package is not necessary in current frameworks and the nuget package got the system confused.